# Fatal error on /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php in Magento

Tags: magento, fatal-error

Just upgraded a Magento install from 1.5 to 1.6, and left with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in
>   /hsphere/local/home/t21004/XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php
>   on line 133

The contents of line 133 are as below:

```
 return $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insert($this->getMainTable(), $dbModuleInfo);
```

---

config.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Core
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date/>
        </install>
        <resources>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host>localhost</host>
                    <username/>
                    <password/>
                    <dbname>magento</dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>0</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
            <default_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </default_write>
            <default_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </default_read>
            <core_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mage_Core</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </core_setup>
            <core_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_write</use>
                </connection>
            </core_write>
            <core_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>default_read</use>
                </connection>
            </core_read>
        </resources>
        <resource>
            <connection>
                <types>
                    <pdo_mysql>
                        <adapter>Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql</adapter>
                        <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql</class>
                        <compatibleMode>1</compatibleMode>
                    </pdo_mysql>
                </types>
            </connection>
        </resource>
        <models>
            <varien>
                <class>Varien</class>
            </varien>
            <core>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>core_resource</resourceModel>
            </core>
            <core_resource>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource</class>
                <deprecatedNode>core_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                <entities>
                    <config_data>
                        <table>core_config_data</table>
                    </config_data>
                    <website>
                        <table>core_website</table>
                    </website>
                    <store>
                        <table>core_store</table>
                    </store>
                    <resource>
                        <table>core_resource</table>
                    </resource>
                    <cache>
                        <table>core_cache</table>
                    </cache>
                    <cache_tag>
                        <table>core_cache_tag</table>
                    </cache_tag>
                    <cache_option>
                        <table>core_cache_option</table>
                    </cache_option>
                </entities>
            </core_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <system>
            <filesystem>
                <base>{{root_dir}}</base>
                <app>{{root_dir}}/app</app>
                <code>{{app_dir}}/code</code>
                <design>{{app_dir}}/design</design>
                <locale>{{app_dir}}/locale</locale>
                <etc>{{app_dir}}/etc</etc>
                <media>{{root_dir}}/media</media>
                <upload>{{root_dir}}/media/upload</upload>
                <skin>{{root_dir}}/skin</skin>
                <var>{{var_dir}}</var>
                <cache>{{var_dir}}/cache</cache>
                <session>{{var_dir}}/session</session>
                <tmp>{{var_dir}}/tmp</tmp>
                <pear>{{var_dir}}/pear</pear>
                <export>{{var_dir}}/export</export>
            </filesystem>
        </system>
        <general>
            <locale>
                <code>en_US</code>
                <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
            </locale>
        </general>
    </default>
    <varien>
        <class>Varien</class>
    </varien>
</config>
```

and local.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Core
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 26 Apr 2011 15:59:54 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXX]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXX]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXX]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[XXXXXXX]]></dbname>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you please post your /app/etc/config.xml and /app/etc/local.xml files (redacted of course)

Comment: I also faced same issue. In my case in app/etc/local.xml.template file was not there so magento was creating empty local.xml file. Magento was trying to connect using write/read adapter but connection not established because local.xml file was empty. In file app\code\core\Mage\Install\Model\Installer\Config.php on line 103 magento trying to fetch content of local.xml.template file and creating local.xml file. This is happen because we haven't kept local.xml.template file as part of our git code.

Comment: I am having the same issue, same file, same line. Must be something wrong with Magento itself. I deleted all third party (local and community) modules, by removing their .xml files from app/etc/modules directory, leaving only the magento native modules inside. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 8):

This error boils down to a config problem.  The setup model is trying to install/upgrade some module in your install and failing when it cannot find a write connection for the resource.  This would seem to indicate one of two places that has a broken config: The global config (/app/etc/*.xml) or a specific module config (etc/config.xml in the module).

The problem module may have a config section /config/global/resources that contains references to setup/read/write connections.  Check if that is the case and if the reference for the write connection is correct.  If it's not a specific module, check the global resources core_(read|write|setup) and default_(read|write|setup) for correctness.

Comment: Well The problem I found was new parameter for database connection is set from Magento 1.6 onwards. Please check these added parameters in your local.xml
 `<model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType> `

Answer (score 2):

Please go to the `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php`, line 402, you will see there

```
protected function _initModules() 
{
 ...
```

Put after `{` this code `print_r(Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources'));exit();` and show us what you got on the screen. In my case I see next thing:

```
Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
(
    [default_setup] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [connection] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [host] => localhost
                    [username] => root
                    [password] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                        (
                        )

                    [dbname] => magento
                    [initStatements] => SET NAMES utf8
                    [model] => mysql4
                    [type] => pdo_mysql
                    [pdoType] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                        (
                        )

                    [active] => 1
                )

        )

    [default_write] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [connection] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [use] => default_setup
                )

        )

    [default_read] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [connection] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [use] => default_setup
                )

        )

    [core_setup] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [setup] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [module] => Mage_Core
                )

            [connection] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [use] => default_setup
                )

        )

    [core_write] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [connection] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [use] => default_write
                )

        )

    [core_read] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [connection] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                    [use] => default_read
                )

        )

    [db] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [table_prefix] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You are asking for clarification on the problem, not providing an answer.  This should have been a comment on the question.

Comment: @Lee Saferite I know, but this question can't be inserted to comment box because of chars number limit. Blame on stackoverflow interface... Next time I'll better not ask anything in this case at all, thanks to all who pressed -1.

Comment: @Zyava dont loose heart buddy  +1 for your contribution

Answer (score 2):

I also run into similar issue.

In my case while installing Magento when I fill all the db details and click on continute I was getting below Fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function insert() on boolean in /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php on line 133"
```

Magento was trying to connect using write/read adapter but connection not established because local.xml file was empty.

In file app\code\core\Mage\Install\Model\Installer\Config.php on line 103 magento trying to fetch content of local.xml.template file and creating local.xml file nodes.

```
    $template = file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('etc') . DS . 'local.xml.template');
    foreach ($data as $index => $value) {
        $template = str_replace('{{' . $index . '}}', '<![CDATA[' . $value . ']]>', $template);
    }
    file_put_contents($this->_localConfigFile, $template);
```

So I checked there in app/etc/local.xml.template file was not present because we haven't kept it part of our git code. After placing local.xml.template file issue resolved.

I hope this will help others.

Comment: Also check `local.xml` file permission and ownership.

Comment: Wait! Shouldn't the `install.php` script take care of creating the `local.xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of the file permissions, I had the same problem.
Just make sure you are installing magento with the appropiate file permissions (eg: the user is the owner of the files)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that your *magento/lib* directory is not updated. If you did the manual process as I did, you might have missed updating that dir. I discovered that there are quite a few reasons why the connection object might be blank:

- Invalid configuration (may be missing stuff needed for 1.6+, may have wrong information, may be cached with old data) - seems that `var/cache` files might be responsible also, depending on how your caching is set up.
- Something is really messed up in the module configuration. In our case, this wasn't the issue: core_setup was the module being upgraded.
- Old versions of class files (seems to apply for vers less than 1.6 updating to 1.6+) in particular, when creating or getting the connection objects, it looks to see if it extends a new interface, `Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface`.
- The possibility of bad file permissions messing things up exists, as always.

For the third, a quick check of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php` shows reasons why the _connection data members might be invalid. One of the main checks it makes is to see if the connection object created is an instance of (includes a subclass of) `Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface`. From the libraries for 1.4.1.1 (in our case)

`class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql extends Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql`

But in 1.6+

`class Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql extends Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql implements Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface`

ergo, the check fails and even with valid configurations, you don't get connection objects. It is poor programming on their part that it doesn't *REPORT* this problem *VERY SPECIFICALLY* since it creates an error state behavior *identical to, but not at all related to*, another common error: misconfiguration of the database connection. It's not like it's a passive check. They explicitly check for the new interface, but then don't log or produce any kind of *potential* debug information regarding it.

As a final note, during the upgrade if you have lots of stuff, you may wish to explicitly log this failure in case something somewhere in your code IS using an old DB adapter somehow. (in our case, some code written by another contractor had overridden the adapter in the `local` namespace, which generated this error again.)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to set the database connection in config.xml so `<active>1</active>`

IMHO Magento should raise an exception in Mage_Core_Model_Resource when the connection is not active, instead of just returning false and propagating this false value to where it is expected to be an object.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, when I have rewritten method _construct from parent Model Resource class, but I've forgotten to insert, aparat my custom logic, essentail line in every Resource model constructor:

```
$this->_init('catalog/category_flat', 'entity_id');
```

When I put that back, all worked like charm.