# Magento(1.7) fatal error while installation

Tags: php, magento

I am getting following error while installing magento (1.7)

```
Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php on line 133, while installing magento
```

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190461/fatal-error-on-app-code-core-mage-core-model-resource-resource-php-in-magento

Comment: I resolved the issue by giving write permissions to etc folder. :)

Comment: Give a green check to the correct answer.

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano , its not allowing me to do it today,I can do it tommorrow

Comment: @urfusion, ur link says `local.xml` is missing in the `app/etc/` dir and that it should be there. But, shouldn't the `install.php` take care of creating it using the envs given to the container (e.g. `MYSQL_HOST`, `MYSQL_PASSWORD`, and so on)?

Comment: @mhyousefi Are you trying to install magento 1.7?

Comment: @urfusion 1.9.4.1 to be exact :) Also, there's more details as to what's happening here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61069896/magento-1-getting-fatal-error-while-accessing-installation-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I given 777 permission to my app/etc folder and my issue resolved.

Comment: For the sake of security, it should be 640 permission, which is writable by owner and readable by group user.

Comment: I added `RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/app/etc` to my `Dockerfile` and still get this error.